# Flask-marshmallow base_fields.Function in base_fields.Nested

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, hateoas, marshmallow

I am using [flask-marshmallow](http://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) along with [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I would like to have my own kind of HATEOAS implementation: for n-to-many relationships, along with the link, I d like to have the count of objects

For that, I have a regular sqlalchemy model with a many-to-many relationship:

```
class ParentChild(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parrent_child'
    parent_id =Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)

class Parent(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
    children = relationship('Child', secondary='parent_child', back_populates='parents')

class Child(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())
    parents = relationship('Parent', secondary='parent_child', back_populates='children')
```

Using the following marshmallow schema, I manage to get the data I want:

```
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
    children = URLFor('api.parents_children_by_parent_id', parent_id='<id>')
    children_count = base_fields.Function(lambda obj: len(obj.children))
```

Returns:

```
{
    "id" : 42,
    "name" : "Bob",
    "children" : "/api/parents/42/children",
    "children_count" : 3
}
```

But I have issues when I want to encapsulate the fields like this:

```
{
     "id": 42
     "name": "bob",
     "children": {
         "link": "/api/parents/42/children",
         "count": 3
     }
}
```

I tried using a `base_fields.Dict`:

```
children = base_fields.Dict(
    link = URLFor('api.parents_children_by_parent_id', parent_id='<id>'),
    count = base_fields.Function(lambda obj: len(obj.children))
)
```

But I get
`TypeError: Object of type 'Child' is not JSON serializable`

I tried various other solutions, without success :
flask-marshmallow's `Hyperlinks` only accepts
 dictionaries of Hyperlinks, and not Functions.

I think the solution would be to use a `base_fields.Nested` but it breaks the behaviour of `URLFor` that cannot catch the `'<id>'`.
I can't find a solution to this in the documentation.

At some point it s hard to think out of the box. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `Model` of `marshmellow_sqlalchemy.ModelSchema` type? And is `base_fields` the same as `marshmellow.fields?

Comment: `Model` is of type `db.Model`, `db` being my `SQLAlchemy` object, from `flask_sqlalchemy`. `base_fields` is from `flask_marshmallow`, which I think is roughly the same as `marshmallow.fields`, except that `flask_marshmallow` has `URLFor` and few others.

Answer (score 4):

So I found a workaround that I'm going to post, but I think it can be improved.

To override the `children` field with the object I want, I use a `base_fields.Method`:

```
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent

    children = base_fields.Method('build_children_obj')

    def build_children_obj(self, obj):
        return {
            "count": len(obj.children),
            "link": URLFor('api.parents_children_by_parent_id', parent_id=obj.id)
        }
```

At that point, I was getting `TypeError: Object of type 'URLFor' is not JSON serializable`

So after checking the source of the `_serialize` method of `URLFor` I added a check in my (customized) JSONEncoder:

```
if isinstance(o, URLFor):
    return str(o._serialize(None, None, o))
```

And I finally got the payload I wanted, but I dont find it very clean. Any ideas?

EDIT : After testing, I found that `len(obj.children)` to get the count was very expensive in resources by loading the entire list of children. Instead, I do `db.session.query(func.count(Children.id)).filter(Children.parents.any(id=obj.id)).scalar()` Which is more optimized.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, saved me a lot of time =)

Comment: can you show where to exactly add (customized) JSONEncoder?